# Displaying Total Number of Drawing_Line_Items__c on Drawings__c in Salesforce using apex class

Tags: apex, trigger

To follow best practices, I am writing Apex Class instead of Apex Trigger. I have a Object called Drawing__c and Drawing_Line_Items__c having Lookup relationship. I want to update count of Drawing_Line_Items__c on Drawing__c. As per my Code Count is updating, but when I delete Drawing_Line_Items__c  record, Count did not updating. Below is the code of Updating Count.Kindly anyone help with how to write class for Delete method and update count.

```
Apex Class:

public class DrawingLineitemsSendCountonDrawing {
public static void AfterInsert(List<Drawing_Line_Items__c> newList){
        List<Drawing_Line_Items__c> DrawingList = new List<Drawing_Line_Items__c>();
        List<Drawing__c> DrawList = new List<Drawing__c>();
        Map<Id, List<Drawing_Line_Items__c>> DrawingLineItemsList = new Map<Id, List<Drawing_Line_Items__c>>();
        Set<Id> DrawingIds = new Set<Id>();
        //Map<String,String> DrawingLineItemsMap = New Map<String,String>();
        for(Drawing_Line_Items__c draw :newList){
            if(String.isNotBlank(draw.Drawing_Number__c) ){
                DrawingIds.add(draw.Drawing_Number__c);  
            } 
        } 
        if(DrawingIds.size() > 0){
            DrawingList = [SELECT Id, Shop_Drawing_Quantity__c, Drawing_Number__c FROM Drawing_Line_Items__c WHERE  Shop_Drawing_Quantity__c != 0 AND Shop_Drawing_Quantity__c != NULL  AND Drawing_Number__c IN : DrawingIds ];
            for(Drawing_Line_Items__c draw : DrawingList) {  
                if(!DrawingLineItemsList.containsKey(draw.Drawing_Number__c)){ 
                    DrawingLineItemsList.put(draw.Drawing_Number__c, new List<Drawing_Line_Items__c>());
                }
                DrawingLineItemsList.get(draw.Drawing_Number__c).add(draw);    
            } 
            System.debug('Drawing Id and Drawing Line Items List Map is ' + DrawingLineItemsList);
            DrawList = [SELECT Drawing_Line_Items_Count__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE Id IN : DrawingIds];
            for(Drawing__c Drawing : DrawList) {
                List<Drawing_Line_Items__c> DrawingList1 = new List<Drawing_Line_Items__c>();
                DrawingList1 = DrawingLineItemsList.get(Drawing.Id);
                Drawing.Drawing_Line_Items_Count__c= DrawingList1.size();    
            } 
            System.debug('Drawing List is ' + DrawList);
            update DrawList;    
        }
    }   
  }
```

Trigger Class:

```
trigger DrawingLineItems on Drawing_Line_Items__c (after insert, after Update, after delete, after undelete) {
// After Insert Count of Drawing Line Item goes to Drawing.
        // Calling Class from Trigger 
        if(Trigger.isAfter){
        DrawingLineitemsSendCountonDrawing.AfterInsert(Trigger.New);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You probably have already considered this, but is there a reason you're not using a master-detail relationship between your objects and a roll-up summary to get the COUNT?

Comment: +1 to changing the relationship to use roll-up summaries. If that isn't possible, then there are several open source options for implementing rollups. https://github.com/jamessimone/apex-rollup and https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries

Comment: No we purposely using Lookup relationship. Is there any way we can delete drawing line items and count update on Drawing by using apex class?

Comment: DLRS works on lookup relationships and handles deletes as well as insert/updates; it's free and widely used

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: As mentioned, [DLRS](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/topics/dlrs?sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC) is the easiest solution.  If you want to write your own Apex, then remember that `AfterDelete` uses `Trigger.old`

Comment: Yes that I know,but my code not working

Comment: So as my code was working fine, the issue was in passing the parameters. Here is the Whole Working Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as my code was working fine, the issue was in passing the parameters. Here is the Whole Working Code.

```
public class DrawingLineitemsSendCountonDrawing {
    
public static void AfterInsert(List<Drawing_Line_Items__c> newList){
        List<Drawing_Line_Items__c> DrawingList = new List<Drawing_Line_Items__c>();
        List<Drawing__c> DrawList = new List<Drawing__c>();
        Map<Id, List<Drawing_Line_Items__c>> DrawingLineItemsList = new Map<Id, List<Drawing_Line_Items__c>>();
        Set<Id> DrawingIds = new Set<Id>();
        //Map<String,String> DrawingLineItemsMap = New Map<String,String>();
        for(Drawing_Line_Items__c draw :newList){
            if(String.isNotBlank(draw.Drawing_Number__c) ){
                DrawingIds.add(draw.Drawing_Number__c);  
            } 
        } 
        if(DrawingIds.size() > 0){
            DrawingList = [SELECT Id, Shop_Drawing_Quantity__c, Drawing_Number__c FROM Drawing_Line_Items__c WHERE  Shop_Drawing_Quantity__c != 0 AND Shop_Drawing_Quantity__c != NULL  AND Drawing_Number__c IN : DrawingIds ];
            for(Drawing_Line_Items__c draw : DrawingList) {  
                if(!DrawingLineItemsList.containsKey(draw.Drawing_Number__c)){ 
                    DrawingLineItemsList.put(draw.Drawing_Number__c, new List<Drawing_Line_Items__c>());
                }
                DrawingLineItemsList.get(draw.Drawing_Number__c).add(draw);    
            } 
            System.debug('Drawing Id and Drawing Line Items List Map is ' + DrawingLineItemsList);
            DrawList = [SELECT Drawing_Line_Items_Count__c FROM Drawing__c WHERE Id IN : DrawingIds];
            for(Drawing__c Drawing : DrawList) {
                List<Drawing_Line_Items__c> DrawingList1 = new List<Drawing_Line_Items__c>();
                DrawingList1 = DrawingLineItemsList.get(Drawing.Id);
                Drawing.Drawing_Line_Items_Count__c= DrawingList1.size(); 
                 System.debug('Drawing.Drawing_Line_Items_Count__c : ' + Drawing.Drawing_Line_Items_Count__c );
            } 
            System.debug('Drawing List is ' + DrawList);
           
            update DrawList;    
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger

```
//-----------------------------Using Below FrameWork for DrawingLineitemsSendCountonDrawing Class-------------------------//
            if(Trigger.isAfter){
                if(Trigger.isInsert){
            DrawingLineitemsSendCountonDrawing.AfterInsert(Trigger.New);
        } 
    }
        if(Trigger.isAfter){
                if(Trigger.isUndelete){
            DrawingLineitemsSendCountonDrawing.AfterInsert(Trigger.New);
        } 
    }
        if(Trigger.isAfter){
                if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            DrawingLineitemsSendCountonDrawing.AfterInsert(Trigger.New);
        } 
    }
        if(Trigger.isAfter){
                if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            DrawingLineitemsSendCountonDrawing.AfterInsert(Trigger.Old);
        } 
    }
        if(Trigger.isAfter){
                if(Trigger.isDelete){
            DrawingLineitemsSendCountonDrawing.AfterInsert(Trigger.Old);
        } 
    }
```